# return escape spaces with pwd

Tags: pwd

```
printf "%q\n" "$(pwd)"
```

zSH Catalina OSX returns

/Volumes/Public/Photos/Paris\ 2016/Musee\ Rodin\ 2016

I would like the result in a variable so that it can be used in a script.  What is the simplest command or solution?

Comment: The obvious first reaction is to ask why you need escaping and why the `$PWD` variable won't do.  Why did you delete the part of the question that explains that, and that tells answerers that it's not actually _shell escaping_ that you need in the first place?

Comment: @JdeBP   It turns out that I needed to actually put the string in double quotes and did not need the escape spaces, however, I am still curious how to solve the problem.

Comment: You've deleted the problem that needed solving from the question.  This question is a non-problem as it stands, because it doesn't explain why the shell variable that _already exists_ won't do.